# Python - Retrieve ".txt" file v

Tags: python, subprocess, wget

I'm trying to **retrieve a ".txt" file via a wget command inside my python file** (python 2.7)

Here the code I'm using :

````
```
product_file = subprocess.check_output([
                             'wget',
                             '--http-user=example@example.ch',
                             '--http-password=example',
                             '--no-check-certificate',
                             '--output-document=file.txt',
                             '--no-cache',
                             '--auth-no-challenge',
                             'https://www.example.com',
                             'shell=True'
                         ])
catalog = open(product_file)
```
````

When I'm running the code, I'm having this error :

```
RuntimeError: Command '['wget', '--http-user=example@example.ch', '--http-password=example', '--no-check-certificate', '--output-document=catalog.txt', '--no-cache', '--auth-no-challenge', 'https://www.example.com', 'shell=True']' return with error (code 1)
```

When I try the wget command in my terminal, it works ; I'm able to retrieve the file ".txt".
I already checked file/directory permissions.

I read the python documentation about the subprocess module and I don't understand every details (I don't have a lot of experience) ; There is surely something I'm missing with this subprocess module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the `shell=True`. You meant it as a keyword argument for the `subprocess.check_output` function, not as a part of the `wget` command.
You actually want to pass the `shell` kwargs to the `check_output` function instead:

```py
product_file = subprocess.check_output([
                             'wget',
                             '--http-user=example@example.ch',
                             '--http-password=example',
                             '--no-check-certificate',
                             '--output-document=file.txt',
                             '--no-cache',
                             '--auth-no-challenge',
                             'https://www.example.com'
                         ], shell=True)
catalog = open(product_file)
```

(There also was a parenthesis problem)

Comment: @ RobBlanchard Hello ! You were right. There was indeed a problem with the parenthesis and the "shell=True" parameter is not part of the "wget" command but of the "subprocess.check_output" method. Nevertheless, the correction of these two errors was not enough to execute the command correctly. To do this, I had to put the <URL> parameter first and not last.This is odd, because according to the wget manual the URL should be in the last position. Thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
product_file = subprocess.check_output(
    'wget --http-user=example@example.ch --http-password=example --no-check-certificate --output-document=file.txt --no-cache --auth-no-challenge https://www.example.com', shell=True)
```